# public post preview plug in - can you adjust preview length to a month?

Tags: wordpress, post, plugins, preview, public

Extending length of the preview duration to 4 weeks - could this cause problems? Background: In Wordpress I'm using the plug-in Public Post Preview. The plug in allows unpublished posts to be viewed by anyone as long as they have access to the plug-in's generated link (to the post). The plug in's preview has a default time of 48 hours. I can use this function to extend the duration, in the case to 7 days.

```
    add_filter( 'ppp_nonce_life', 'my_nonce_life' );
    function my_nonce_life() {
        return 60 * 60 * 24 * 7; // 7 days
    }
```

I have been asked to extend the duration to 4 weeks (using this function) - I'm not sure if this would affect performance of my site etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can try
    
    `add_filter( 'ppp_nonce_life', 'my_nonce_life' );
    function my_nonce_life() {
        return 60 * 60 * 24 * 28; // 28 days
    }`